# Resized Image ( 320x480) is not full screen? What is the full screen size for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, fullscreen

I'm trying to to resize my image (from URL) to full screen in my iPhone. However, the size 320x480 which is supposed to be full size is not full screen.

```
-(IBAction)changeFullSize{
    urlImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    urlImage.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
}
```

I'm using a `UIButton` here, so when the user clicks on the opaque button, it changes to a full sized image.

However, there is an empty space between the tab bar at the top and the start of the picture.

What is the correct size for full screen? Is there a way for it to automatically resize to full screen without me specifying the width and height?

Thanks.

Comment: May be it is a problem of aspect ratio. What is the actual size of the image?

Answer (score 2):

You could try and get it from `self.view.frame.size` but for the entire screen you can use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I combined Mark's and user809827 answer. It worked! Thanks a bunch! 
This is what I did:

urlImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    urlImage.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

Answer (score 2):

you cant just resize your image by changing its frame, since you are using aspect fit, the image will keep its original aspect, depending on your needs a simple way would be to change to UIViewContentModeScaleToFill

if scaling to fill does not produce your intended results, you may want to check out trevor's blog post on uiimage categories [here](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/)
once the UIImage categories are added you can just perform

```
[youruiimage resizedImage:CGSizeMake(320, 480) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh]
```

using this you can use either UIViewContentModeScaleToFill or UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit and it should turn out nicely =)

Answer (score 1):

If you have status bar then don't forget to reduce its size from the height.

And also aspect-fit would keep the image in its correct ratio, then consider filling it.

Aspect-fill would keep the image in correct ration + will try to make full screen, no void spaces, chances are some part of image wont be shown.

Scale to fill will keep the image full screen, ratio doesn't matter there.